# Accessing model data in django

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

I have a a Django model:

```
class Myvalues(models.Model):
        items_list = models.JSONField()
```

I have populated this model in Django admin. I now want to access the data inside this model. However I am getting an error that says:  `'Manager' object has no attribute ‘items_list'`
The way I am trying to access it is as follows:

```
Print(Myvalues.objects.items_list.values())
```

I don’t understand why this is coming up as the class has that model in it.
Out of interest I printed the `all()` result of `Myvalues` class, like so:

```
print(Myvalues.objects.all())
```

this resulted in the following:

```
<QuerySet [<Myvalues: Myvalues object (1)>]>
```

How can I access the data that’s in my items_list model?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the following syntax instead ([documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/querysets/#values-list)).

```
Myvalues.objects.values_list('items_list', flat=True)
```

If you want to have tuples returned, omit `flat=True`.

Comment: great stuff thank you

Answer (score 1):

```
Myvalues.objects
```

returns a `django.db.models.manager.Manager` object, not a `Myvalues: Myvalues object`

In order to request the `items_list` use

```
Myvalues.objects.all()[i].item_list
```

It returns all the `Myvalue` objects and picks one with the index. From this object you can get your model properties.